# Using 'findAndModify' on mongodb within multiple nested array (complex)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have the next document in a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("546a7a0f44aee82db8469f6d"),
    ...
    "valoresVariablesIterativas" : [ 
        {
            "asignaturaVO" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("546a389c44aee54fc83112e9")
            },
            "valoresEstaticos" : {
                "IT_VAR3" : "",
                "IT_VAR1" : "",
                "IT_VAR2" : "asdasd"
            },
            "valoresPreestablecidos" : {
                "IT_ASIGNATURA" : "Matemáticas",
                "IT_NOTA_DEFINITIVA_ASIGNATURA" : ""
            }
        }, 
        {
            "asignaturaVO" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("546a3d8d44aee54fc83112fa")
            },
            "valoresEstaticos" : {
                "IT_VAR3" : "",
                "IT_VAR1" : "",
                "IT_VAR2" : ""
            },
            "valoresPreestablecidos" : {
                "IT_ASIGNATURA" : "Español",
                "IT_NOTA_DEFINITIVA_ASIGNATURA" : ""
            }
        }
    ]
    ...
}
```

I want modify an element of the valoresEstaticos, I know the fields "_id", "asignaturaVO", and the key of the item valoresEstaticos that I want modify.

Which is the correct query for this?, I have this:

```
db.myCollection.findAndModify({
    query:{"_id" : ObjectId("546a7a0f44aee82db8469f6d")},
    update: { 
              {valoresVariablesIterativas.asignaturaVO._id:    ObjectId("546a389c44aee54fc83112e9")},
              { $set: {}}
    }
})
```

but I dont know how to build a query :(

Help me please, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `update`.

```
db.myCollection.update(
    { "_id" : ObjectId("546a7a0f44aee82db8469f6d"), "valoresVariablesIterativas.asignaturaVO._id" : ObjectId("546a389c44aee54fc83112e9") },
    { "$set" : { "valoresVariablesIterativas.$.valoresEstaticos.IT_VAR3" : 99 } }
)
```

assuming you want to update key `IT_VAR3`. The key is the [positional update operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). The condition on the array in the query portion of the update is redundant for finding the document, but necessary to use the $ to update the correct array element.

Comment: You are right, but I need findAndModify because this query will run via MongoTemplate (spring-data) and many user can modify the same document at the time. Another problems is that the key of valoresEstaticos can be variable. Thanks!